# Is Browserify compatible with Polymer and/or AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, polymer, browserify

I'd like to use a NodeJS library in my Polymer/AngularJS applications. To do so, I aim to run Browserify on the NodeJS module I wish to use and then reference it in a Polymer web component and also in an AngularJS controller. As far as I can tell, Browserify merely adds `require()` to the global namespace and so there should not have any naming conflicts.

Is there anything I'm missing or will these technologies work together?

Comment: Angular works well with browserify, from angular 1.3.15.

Answer (score 3):

Browserify works fine with Polymer.  I normally expose modules using browserify's [--standalone](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) flag then integrate as a Polymer elements [behavior](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html).

Comment: Created example here: https://github.com/jrmerz/polymer-browserify-example.  Note, there is more than one way to do this. My simple example uses a global namespace which is not great for creating redistributable components.

Answer (score 0):

I find out a way to use Polymer with webpack [polymer-ext](https://github.com/yutingzhao1991/polymer-ext)

If you want ues browserify with polymer, maybe you should try the same way.

Answer (score 0):

As another, not so sophisticated approach that doesn't use standalone or behaviours but is maybe a bit more flexible, I've gone with defining a global variable `APP`. Then defining a `get` function that returns one of the global required modules.

eg

```
// in main index.html file before elements.html imported define global namespace
<script>
var APP = {};
</script>
```

Make a test module

```
// services/test.js
module.exports = {
  test: function(){
    console.log('imt the test function');
  }
}
```

Then in main js file.

```
// main js file
(function(APP) {

 var globalModules = {
    test: require('./services/test')
 } 

 APP.get = function(moduleName){
    return globalModules[moduleName];
 }

})(APP);
```

Then this can be used inside Polymer elements when required like

```
APP.get('test').test();
```

Not sure what the standpoint would be on whether this would be the "proper" way to do it but it works for what I was trying to achieve and may help someone.